# Associating a MouseListener with a JComponent

Tags: java, swing

My question here is that when the local class `MouseClickListener` calls the `moveTo` method of the `comp` object before we do: `comp.addMouseListener(listener);`, then why do the latter at all?

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Scratch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Moving Rectangle");
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        final MyComponent comp = new MyComponent(); 
        class MouseClickListener implements MouseListener {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {}
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {}
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
                int x = event.getX();
                int y = event.getY();
                comp.moveTo(x, y);
            }
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event) {}
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event) {}
        }
        MouseListener listener = new MouseClickListener();
        comp.addMouseListener(listener);
        frame.add(comp);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class MyComponent extends JComponent {

    private Rectangle box;
    public MyComponent() {
        box = new Rectangle(0,0,50,50);
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g; 
        g2.draw(box);
    }
    public void moveTo(int x, int y) {
        box.setLocation(x,y);
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post more detail about your problem and your code. Try telling us what your classes and methods are supposed to do, the details of how things are misbehaving. The more effort you put into asking a clear unambiguous question, the better the possible answers you might see.

Comment: Don't shout!! there is no reason to bold your question! Also, given that you have not yet "accepted" a single answer from any of your previous 18 questions, I'll skip this one since you don't appreciate the time people spend helping you solve a problem.

Comment: @camickr: I thought CAPS was shouting. I put it in bold so that it highlights the main question I'm trying to ask. I just joined this site like last week and I'm new to how things work around here. I have no idea that I needed to accept an answer. You come off as a really rude person and you should understand the scenario better before making random remarks. Have a nice day.

Comment: `I have no idea that I needed to accept an answer.` You have been reminded several time. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29478480/131872 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/29478353/131872. Saying "thank you" is part of daily life when someone helps you.  `I just joined this site like last week and I'm new to how things work around here` and you can learn by example by looking at other posted questions to see how those people "accept" answers and how questions don't use bold text.

Comment: Ok, I get your point. I'll do that from now on. Does accepting an answer stop inviting new answers? If so, that's bad because I would like to know various perspectives before I accept the answer.

Comment: `Does accepting an answer stop inviting new answers?` No. An answer can be given at any time if people think there is a better solution. `I would like to know various perspectives before I accept the answer` - that's fine to wait a little as there can always be more than one solution to a problem. The key point is not to forget the effort people make.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By calling `comp.addMouseListener(listener);` you specify to listen on your component `comp` using the `listener` implementation you defined.

---

As per your edit, you want to know why is it called in that order.

Actually, it's the first statement after instantiating the `listener` so it could not be done before. It would fail if you would try to listen on a non-instantiated listener.

```
MouseListener listener = new MouseClickListener();
comp.addMouseListener(listener);
```

Note that if you don't plan on re-using the listener you could simply do

```
comp.addMouseListener(new MouseClickListener());
```

You must not rely on where is declared the inner class, the listener could be added before that part. However you can't ommit assigning it to your component, simply declaring the class won't listen directly to each of your object. It need to be assigned.

Comment: I understand that, but we do this after everything's been done. If everything's done, they why do this at all?

Comment: @BloodBrother, `Just know that I appreciate your effort. Thanks man. :)` - then "accept" the answer. All you have to do is click on the check mark.